# Stack overflow in a recursive function

Tags: c, stack-overflow

I have two functions, I could get rid of the one that makes the mistake, but I don't really want to rewrite almost all my code away, so I need to fix that in any other way.

```
int Reveal(char*** arr, int** n, int i, int j) {    
    if (n[i][j] == 0) { arr[i][j] = "0"; }
    else { arr[i][j] = "\033[0;36m4\033[0;37m"; }
}
int SUPERreveal(char*** ARRAY, int** MasPLAY, int choose_pos, int choose_pos2, int difficulty) {
    Reveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos, choose_pos2);

    if (choose_pos == 0) {
        if (choose_pos2 == 0) {
            if (MasPLAY[choose_pos + 1][choose_pos2 + 1] != 9) { 
                Reveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos + 1, choose_pos2 + 1); 
                if (MasPLAY[choose_pos + 1][choose_pos2 + 1] == 0) SUPERreveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos + 1, choose_pos2 + 1, difficulty);
            }
            if (MasPLAY[choose_pos + 1][choose_pos2] != 9) { 
                Reveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos + 1, choose_pos2); 
                if (MasPLAY[choose_pos + 1][choose_pos2] == 0) SUPERreveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos + 1, choose_pos2, difficulty);
            }
            if (MasPLAY[choose_pos][choose_pos2 + 1] != 9) { 
                Reveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos, choose_pos2 + 1); 
                if (MasPLAY[choose_pos][choose_pos2 + 1] == 0) SUPERreveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos, choose_pos2 + 1, difficulty);
            }
        }
        else if (choose_pos2 > 0 && choose_pos2 < difficulty - 1) {
            if (MasPLAY[choose_pos + 1][choose_pos2 + 1] != 9) { 
                Reveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos + 1, choose_pos2 + 1); 
                if (MasPLAY[choose_pos + 1][choose_pos2 + 1] == 0) SUPERreveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos + 1, choose_pos2 + 1, difficulty);
            }
            if (MasPLAY[choose_pos][choose_pos2 - 1] != 9) { 
                Reveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos, choose_pos2 - 1); 
                if (MasPLAY[choose_pos][choose_pos2 - 1] == 0) SUPERreveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos, choose_pos2 - 1, difficulty);
            }
            if (MasPLAY[choose_pos + 1][choose_pos2] != 9) { 
                Reveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos + 1, choose_pos2);
                if (MasPLAY[choose_pos + 1][choose_pos2] == 0) SUPERreveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos + 1, choose_pos2, difficulty);
            }
            if (MasPLAY[choose_pos][choose_pos2 + 1] != 9) { 
                Reveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos, choose_pos2 + 1); 
                if (MasPLAY[choose_pos][choose_pos2 + 1] == 0) SUPERreveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos, choose_pos2 + 1, difficulty);
            }
            if (MasPLAY[choose_pos + 1][choose_pos2 - 1] != 9) { 
                Reveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos + 1, choose_pos2 - 1); 
                if (MasPLAY[choose_pos + 1][choose_pos2 - 1] == 0) SUPERreveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos + 1, choose_pos2 - 1, difficulty);
            }
        }
        else if (choose_pos2 == difficulty - 1) {
            if (MasPLAY[choose_pos][choose_pos2 - 1] != 9) { 
                Reveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos, choose_pos2 - 1); 
                if (MasPLAY[choose_pos][choose_pos2 - 1] == 0) SUPERreveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos, choose_pos2 - 1, difficulty);
            }
            if (MasPLAY[choose_pos + 1][choose_pos2] != 9) { 
                Reveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos + 1, choose_pos2); 
                if (MasPLAY[choose_pos + 1][choose_pos2] == 0) SUPERreveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos + 1, choose_pos2, difficulty);
            }
            if (MasPLAY[choose_pos + 1][choose_pos2 - 1] != 9) { 
                Reveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos + 1, choose_pos2 - 1); 
                if (MasPLAY[choose_pos + 1][choose_pos2 - 1] == 0) SUPERreveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos + 1, choose_pos2 - 1, difficulty);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (choose_pos > 0 && choose_pos < difficulty - 1) {
        if (choose_pos2 == 0) {
            if (MasPLAY[choose_pos + 1][choose_pos2 + 1] != 9) { 
                Reveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos + 1, choose_pos2 + 1);
                if  (MasPLAY[choose_pos + 1][choose_pos2 + 1] == 0) SUPERreveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos + 1, choose_pos2 + 1, difficulty);
            }
            if (MasPLAY[choose_pos - 1][choose_pos2] != 9) { 
                Reveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos - 1, choose_pos2);
                if (MasPLAY[choose_pos - 1][choose_pos2] == 0) SUPERreveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos - 1, choose_pos2, difficulty);
            }
            if (MasPLAY[choose_pos + 1][choose_pos2] != 9) { 
                Reveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos + 1, choose_pos2); 
                if (MasPLAY[choose_pos + 1][choose_pos2] != 9) SUPERreveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos + 1, choose_pos2, difficulty);
            }
            if (MasPLAY[choose_pos][choose_pos2 + 1] != 9) { 
                Reveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos, choose_pos2 + 1); 
                if (MasPLAY[choose_pos][choose_pos2 + 1] == 0) SUPERreveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos, choose_pos2 + 1, difficulty);
            }
            if (MasPLAY[choose_pos - 1][choose_pos2 + 1] != 9) { 
                Reveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos - 1, choose_pos2 + 1); 
                if (MasPLAY[choose_pos - 1][choose_pos2 + 1] == 0) SUPERreveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos - 1, choose_pos2 + 1, difficulty);
            }
        }
        else if (choose_pos2 > 0 && choose_pos2 < difficulty - 1) {
            if (MasPLAY[choose_pos - 1][choose_pos2 - 1] != 9) { 
                Reveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos - 1, choose_pos2 - 1); 
                if (MasPLAY[choose_pos - 1][choose_pos2 - 1] == 0) SUPERreveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos - 1, choose_pos2 - 1, difficulty);
            }
            if (MasPLAY[choose_pos + 1][choose_pos2 + 1] != 9) { 
                Reveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos + 1, choose_pos2 + 1); 
                if (MasPLAY[choose_pos + 1][choose_pos2 + 1] == 0) SUPERreveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos + 1, choose_pos2 + 1, difficulty);
            }
            if (MasPLAY[choose_pos - 1][choose_pos2] != 9) { 
                Reveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos - 1, choose_pos2); 
                if (MasPLAY[choose_pos - 1][choose_pos2] == 0) SUPERreveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos - 1, choose_pos2, difficulty);
            }
            if (MasPLAY[choose_pos][choose_pos2 - 1] != 9) { 
                Reveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos, choose_pos2 - 1); 
                if (MasPLAY[choose_pos][choose_pos2 - 1] == 0) SUPERreveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos, choose_pos2 - 1, difficulty);
            }
            if (MasPLAY[choose_pos + 1][choose_pos2] != 9) { 
                Reveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos + 1, choose_pos2); 
                if (MasPLAY[choose_pos + 1][choose_pos2] == 0) SUPERreveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos + 1, choose_pos2, difficulty);
            }
            if (MasPLAY[choose_pos][choose_pos2 + 1] != 9) { 
                Reveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos, choose_pos2 + 1); 
                if (MasPLAY[choose_pos][choose_pos2 + 1] == 0) SUPERreveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos, choose_pos2 + 1, difficulty);
            }
            if (MasPLAY[choose_pos + 1][choose_pos2 - 1] != 9) { 
                Reveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos + 1, choose_pos2 - 1); 
                if (MasPLAY[choose_pos + 1][choose_pos2 - 1] == 0) SUPERreveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos + 1, choose_pos2 - 1, difficulty);
            }
            if (MasPLAY[choose_pos - 1][choose_pos2 + 1] != 9) { 
                Reveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos - 1, choose_pos2 + 1); 
                if (MasPLAY[choose_pos - 1][choose_pos2 + 1] == 0) SUPERreveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos - 1, choose_pos2 + 1, difficulty);
            }
        }
        else if (choose_pos2 == difficulty - 1) {
            if (MasPLAY[choose_pos - 1][choose_pos2 - 1] != 9) { 
                Reveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos - 1, choose_pos2 - 1); 
                if (MasPLAY[choose_pos - 1][choose_pos2 - 1] == 0) SUPERreveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos - 1, choose_pos2 - 1, difficulty);
            }
            if (MasPLAY[choose_pos - 1][choose_pos2] != 9) { 
                Reveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos - 1, choose_pos2); 
                if (MasPLAY[choose_pos - 1][choose_pos2] == 0) SUPERreveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos - 1, choose_pos2, difficulty);
            }
            if (MasPLAY[choose_pos][choose_pos2 - 1] != 9) { 
                Reveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos, choose_pos2 - 1); 
                if (MasPLAY[choose_pos][choose_pos2 - 1] == 0) SUPERreveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos, choose_pos2 - 1, difficulty);
            }
            if (MasPLAY[choose_pos + 1][choose_pos2] != 9) { 
                Reveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos + 1, choose_pos2); 
                if (MasPLAY[choose_pos + 1][choose_pos2] == 0) SUPERreveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos + 1, choose_pos2, difficulty);
            }
            if (MasPLAY[choose_pos + 1][choose_pos2 - 1] != 9) { 
                Reveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos + 1, choose_pos2 - 1); 
                if (MasPLAY[choose_pos + 1][choose_pos2 - 1] == 0) SUPERreveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos + 1, choose_pos2 - 1, difficulty);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (choose_pos == difficulty - 1) {
        if (choose_pos2 == 0) {
            if (MasPLAY[choose_pos - 1][choose_pos2] != 9) { 
                Reveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos - 1, choose_pos2); 
                if (MasPLAY[choose_pos - 1][choose_pos2] == 0) SUPERreveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos - 1, choose_pos2, difficulty);
            }
            if (MasPLAY[choose_pos][choose_pos2 + 1] != 9) { 
                Reveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos, choose_pos2 + 1); 
                if (MasPLAY[choose_pos][choose_pos2 + 1] == 0) SUPERreveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos, choose_pos2 + 1, difficulty);
            }
            if (MasPLAY[choose_pos - 1][choose_pos2 + 1] != 9) { 
                Reveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos - 1, choose_pos2 + 1); 
                if (MasPLAY[choose_pos - 1][choose_pos2 + 1] == 0) SUPERreveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos - 1, choose_pos2 + 1, difficulty);
            }
        }
        else if (choose_pos2 > 0 && choose_pos2 < difficulty - 1) {
            if (MasPLAY[choose_pos - 1][choose_pos2 - 1] != 9) { 
                Reveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos - 1, choose_pos2 - 1); 
                if (MasPLAY[choose_pos - 1][choose_pos2 - 1] == 0) SUPERreveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos - 1, choose_pos2 - 1, difficulty);
            }
            if (MasPLAY[choose_pos - 1][choose_pos2] != 9) { 
                Reveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos - 1, choose_pos2); 
                if (MasPLAY[choose_pos - 1][choose_pos2] == 0) SUPERreveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos - 1, choose_pos2, difficulty);
            }
            if (MasPLAY[choose_pos][choose_pos2 - 1] != 9) { 
                Reveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos, choose_pos2 - 1); 
                if (MasPLAY[choose_pos][choose_pos2 - 1] == 0) SUPERreveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos, choose_pos2 - 1, difficulty);
            }
            if (MasPLAY[choose_pos][choose_pos2 + 1] != 9) { 
                Reveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos, choose_pos2 + 1); 
                if (MasPLAY[choose_pos][choose_pos2 + 1] == 0) SUPERreveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos, choose_pos2 + 1, difficulty);
            }
            if (MasPLAY[choose_pos - 1][choose_pos2 + 1] != 9) { 
                Reveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos - 1, choose_pos2 + 1); 
                if (MasPLAY[choose_pos - 1][choose_pos2 + 1] == 0) SUPERreveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos - 1, choose_pos2 + 1, difficulty);
            }
        }
        else if (choose_pos2 == difficulty - 1) {
            if (MasPLAY[choose_pos - 1][choose_pos2 - 1] != 9) { 
                Reveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos - 1, choose_pos2 - 1); 
                if (MasPLAY[choose_pos - 1][choose_pos2 - 1] == 0) SUPERreveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos - 1, choose_pos2 - 1, difficulty);
            }
            if (MasPLAY[choose_pos - 1][choose_pos2] != 9) { 
                Reveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos - 1, choose_pos2); 
                if (MasPLAY[choose_pos - 1][choose_pos2] == 0) SUPERreveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos - 1, choose_pos2, difficulty);
            }
            if (MasPLAY[choose_pos][choose_pos2 - 1] != 9) { 
                Reveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos, choose_pos2 - 1); 
                if (MasPLAY[choose_pos][choose_pos2 - 1] == 0) SUPERreveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos, choose_pos2 - 1, difficulty);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to optimize it more, any recommendations on that? After all, that would reduce the amount of calls that the recursive function makes to the first one.

I tried to change the stack assigned to the first function, but since I don't know how many calls does the second recursive function does to the first one, I don't know to which value I should change it to.

Comment: "Don't want to rewrite my code". Perhaps you should, and get rid of the wall of unreadable almost-same conditions, and possibly the three-star arguments too. But you are asking two questions: why is it overflowing the stack, and how can you make it more efficient. Having a helper function isn't related to stack overflow. Rewrite the code as many times as you need to get it right.

Comment: I notice that you are using `+1` and `-1` with array indices, but there is no bounds checking. Is there a 'border guard' around the edge of the array?

Comment: thats why i used so many if, i am beginner so i couldnt think of any thing else, if there is a way for border checking that doesnt imply having to write the same thing 40 times am all for it

Comment: It's unclear what the code is supposed to do. But if you want to look at each neighbour, you can do it in a double loop that tests the bounds.

Comment: the base one (the one that used to work) was for a minesweeping game, it checks and counts the amount of bombs around for each element of the matrix, then it would depending on where the user wants it, reveal all blank spaces (neither numbers nor bombs) until the perimeter of said revealed spaces consists of numbers. i couldnt make the last part work and this code is an attempt to do it.

Comment: Since your recursive function doesn't have a whole bunch of locals, chances are your stack overflow is due to runaway recursion. Make sure you don't have a scenario where your logic is walking back and forth between the same positions.

Comment: i didnt thought of that, it would go around re checking the same value making it over flow, thanks! i will get it work on it quickly

Comment: Usually in some kind of recursive board play, I keep a 'visited' status for each position. If it's not set, I can set it and move there, recurse and reset it.

Answer (score 3):

Your code could be tremendously simplified by doing the index validation at the top of function `SUPERreveal()`, and not otherwise distinguishing different categories of positions.  It would additionally be simplified by *looping* over the neighboring positions instead of enumerating each one separately.  Together, that would be something like this:

```
int SUPERreveal(char*** ARRAY, int** MasPLAY, int choose_pos, int choose_pos2, int difficulty) {
    if (0 <= choose_pos && choose_pos < difficulty
             && 0 <= choose_pos2 && choose_pos2 < difficulty) {
        Reveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos, choose_pos2);

        for (int dy = -1; dy < 2; dy++) {
            for (int dx = -1; dx < 2; dx++) {
                if ((dy != 0 || dx != 0) && MasPLAY[choose_pos + dy][choose_pos2 + dx] != 9) {
                    if (MasPLAY[choose_pos + dy][choose_pos2 + dx] == 0) {
                        SUPERreveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos + dy, choose_pos2 + dx, difficulty);
                    } else {
                        // In the other case, the recursive call to SUPERreveal handles this:
                        Reveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos + dy, choose_pos2 + dx); 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In addition to the enormous reduction in code size, that removes the opportunity to introduce errors by modifying the code for some cases inconsistently with others.

But this implementation still inherits a serious flaw from your original: it is prone to revisiting positions that it has already visited.  In any situation where that happens, the recursion will not terminate.  For example, if we start at position (0,0), the `difficulty` is at least 2, and neither `MasPLAY[0][0]` nor `MasPLAY[1][1]` is equal to 9, then the recursion will, in principle, go from (0,0) to (1,1), back to (0,0), back to (1,1), *etc*..  This is why you are getting a stack overflow.

So, track which positions have already been traversed (details left as an exercise) so as to avoid backtracking.

Comment: the code goes out of boundries when dx = -1 and choose_pos = 0, because the result is - 1, but i fixed it quickly, with only one if instead of the wall i had before, i thank you for your help, right now im thinking of changing the values of MasPLAY that the function already checked into another set constant (any number, but bigger than 10), this should also help with the other error i was having where the Flaging of the game would re hide the values i already revealed.

Comment: @Felipe, the code presented *does not* go out of bounds, meaning that it never performs out-of-bounds accesses to the array objects.  It will sometimes execute a recursive call with out-of-bounds `choose_pos` or `choose_pos2` arguments, but such calls have no effect.  That's the most important reason for the bounds check added at the beginning of the function.

Answer (score 1):

I already solved every problem that this code had, thanks to @500 - internal sever error and @John Bollinger I was able to figure out how to solve the stack overflow error. I will leave the code here if any person who has a similar problem to me can solve it easily.

@John Bollinger's code had one issue in my case, since the value for

```
choose_pos + dy;
choose_pos2 + dx;
```

Could be equal to -1 or `difficulty` and that would go out of the range of the arrays, so instead I changed this line:

```
//John Bollinger's
if ((dy != 0 || dx != 0) && MasPLAY[choose_pos + dy][choose_pos2 + dx] != 9)

//mine
int newRow = choose_pos + dy;
int newCol = choose_pos2 + dx;

if (0 <= newRow && newRow < difficulty && 0 <= newCol && newCol < difficulty && (dy != 0 || dx != 0)
```

A small change but for me solved the out of range error.

```
void SUPERreveal(char*** ARRAY, int** MasPLAY, int** MasCHECK, int choose_pos, int choose_pos2, int difficulty) {
    if (0 <= choose_pos && choose_pos < difficulty && 0 <= choose_pos2 && choose_pos2 < difficulty) {
        Reveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, choose_pos, choose_pos2);

        for (int dy = -1; dy < 2; dy++) {
            for (int dx = -1; dx < 2; dx++) {
                int newRow = choose_pos + dy;
                int newCol = choose_pos2 + dx;

                if (0 <= newRow && newRow < difficulty && 0 <= newCol && newCol < difficulty && (dy != 0 || dx != 0) && MasPLAY[newRow][newCol] != 9 && !MasCHECK[newRow][newCol ]) {

                    if (MasPLAY[newRow][newCol] == 0) {
                        MasCHECK[newRow][newCol] = 1;
                        SUPERreveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, MasCHECK, newRow, newCol, difficulty);

                    }
                    else {
                        Reveal(ARRAY, MasPLAY, newRow, newCol);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```